# Remove Inf values from formula before lm in R

Tags: r, formula

Let's say I have use mtcars dataset to set arbitrary formula:

```
data(mtcars)

myFormula <- as.formula("mpg ~ cyl + I(disp / hp) + I(wt^2) + I((qsec + vs) / gear)")
```

I would like to use that formula inside `lm` function, but before that, I would like to remove potential rows that contain `Inf`, `NaN` and `NA`. From example if `disp / hp` result in any `Inf values` I would like to remove rows that contain it. I know I can do that by generate new variable first , remove `Inf` and then run lm with formula, but I would like to do that using formula terms, since it is part of shiny application and formula is input.

My try:

```
formulaTerms <- terms(myFormula)
formulaTerms <- gsub("I", "", labels(formulaTerms))
formulaTermsRatio <- formulaTerms[grep("/", formulaTerms)]

mtcarsDT <- setDT(mtcars)
mtcarsDT <- mtcarsDT[, formulaTermsRatio[1] := sym(formulaTermsRatio[1])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop.terms`.  Assuming that each term is represented by a single column in the model matrix (i.e. no factors with > 2 levels) we compute the model matrix `mm` and find the column numbers, `wx`, of the bad columns.  Then use `drop.terms` to drop those columns from the terms object and extract the formula from the revised terms object.

```
mtcars[1, 3] <- Inf

# is.na is TRUE for NA or NaN; is.infinite is TRUE for Inf or -Inf
is.bad <- function(x) any(is.na(x) | is.infinite(x))

fo_terms <- terms(myFormula)  # myFormula is taken from question
mm <- model.matrix(myFormula, mtcars)
wx <- which(apply(mm[, -1], 2, is.bad))
fo_terms2 <- drop.terms(fo_terms, wx, keep.response = TRUE)
fo2 <- formula(fo_terms2)

myFormula
## mpg ~ cyl + I(disp/hp) + I(wt^2) + I((qsec + vs)/gear)

fo2
## mpg ~ cyl + I(wt^2) + I((qsec + vs)/gear)
```

### Update

If you want to remove bad rows rather than terms from the formula then:

```
lm(myFormula, mtcars, subset = !apply(mm, 1, is.bad))
```

Note that `lm` will automatically remove rows with NAs and NaNs (dependintg on the `na.action` argument) so in this case you could simplify `is.bad` to only check for `Inf` and `-Inf`.

Another approach would be to replace `Inf` and `-Inf` with NA.

```
mtcars[is.infinite(mtcars)] <- NA
```

and then perform `lm` normally.

Comment: I wold like to remove observation (row) that contain `Inf`. I don't want to remove term that contain `Inf`

Comment: The question says you want to remove any Inf values from the **formula**, not from the data.  Please fix the question if that was not what was intended.

Comment: I change the question

Comment: Also see Update to answer.

Comment: Your `is.bad()` function is the same as `!is.finite()`. For example: `x <-  c(1/0, NA, -5/0, atanh(2)); all(!is.finite(x))`.

Comment: We have to be careful about keeping the code reasonably obvious but at any the idea of using is.infinite seems worthwhile and I have incorporated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these values from the data you're regressing on.  Inf will occur where hp==0 or gear==0.

```
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars
myFormula <- as.formula("mpg ~ cyl + I(disp / hp) + I(wt^2) + I((qsec + vs) / gear)")

df <- df[!(df$hp==0 | df$gear==0),]
lm(myFormula,df)

> lm(myFormula,df)

Call:
lm(formula = myFormula, data = df)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)                  cyl           I(disp/hp)              I(wt^2)  I((qsec + vs)/gear)  
            35.5847              -1.9639               1.0707              -0.3671              -0.1699
```

Comment: I don't know in advance what will be denominator in ratio in formula.